# limit query after for foreach loop and keep sort order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
  $m = format_date(time(), 'custom', 'm');
  $sql ="
  SELECT cwf.sport, 
  SUM(cwf .time) AS total
  FROM `data`  ww
  INNER JOIN table cwf ON cwf.id = ww.id
  where ww.nid = 2897  AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ww.submitted)) = {$m}
  GROUP BY sport ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5";  

  $results = db_query($sql)->fetchall();
  collect = array();
 $before = array();
  foreach($results as $object) {
     $name = $object->sport;
     $nid = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE  LOWER(title) = :title AND type = 'sport'", array(":title" => trim(strtolower($name))))->fetchField();
     if($nid) {  
       $minutes = $object->total;
       $count =  db_query('SELECT field_' . $m . '_value FROM {field_revision_field_'. $m . '} WHERE  entity_id = :nid', array(":nid" => $nid))->fetchField();
       $real = round($minutes/$count);
       $before[$name] = $minutes; 
       collect[$name] = $real;    
     }
  }
  uasort(collect, 'cmp');

foreach(collect as $k => $v):?>

           <tr">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td><?php echo $k; ?></td>
                 <td align="right"><?php echo $v; ?></td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $before[$k]; ?></td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>

<?php endforeach;
      echo "</table>";
?>
```

I have this query which prints three columns like this

```
SPORT   Average Total Time
sport1  4       700  
sport2  9       600
sport3  3       800  
sport4  2       500
```

I would like to limit 2 so that it sorts the table descending by average not Total time like this. Right now when I add Limit 5 to the query it sorts by total.  I think it won't be in the SQL at all but maybe use a loop and break statement to only increment the foreach by ++2.

```
    SPORT   Average Total
    sport1  9       600  
    sport2  4       700
    sport3  3       800  
    sport4  2       500
```

Comment: So you want the 5 with the highest total, but you want it sorted by avg desc?  If so why not just wrap your select with the desired values in a different select and order those results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your database model looks like (looks pretty strange from your code..), but wouldn't it be much easier to make it into a single query. Better for performance and then MySQL can solve your ordering issues.

Not tested, lacking your db model/data, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT cwf.sport, ROUND(total / frf.field_' . $m . '_value) AS avg, SUM(cwf .time) AS total
  FROM `data`  ww
  INNER JOIN table cwf ON cwf.id = ww.id
  JOIN {node} n ON LOWER(n.title) = cwf.sport AND n.type='sport'
  JOIN {field_revision_field_'. $m . '} frf ON frf.entity_id = n.nid
  where ww.nid = 2897  AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ww.submitted)) = {$m}
  GROUP BY sport ORDER BY avg DESC LIMIT 5
```